# In Illustrator the Layers panel Options for Selected contains no color assignment.

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, layers

I see that others have more options for the Layers Panel, such as the ability to change color.

My layers panel Options for Selected contains only:

Lock. Hide.

How do I restore the correct functionality?

Comment: Hi and welcome to GD.SE. Could you maybe show a screenshot of other people having this functionality?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but could it be that your colour-space is set to grayscale?

Comment: I mean the ability to assign colors to layers. Layer properties-> as I recall contains "Template" "Opacity" "Color" etc.  But this contains only 'Show' and 'Lock" so something is wrong there.

Comment: You'll want to open the layer's options, select 'Options for "~YOURLAYER"...' and choose the color there. That is, in CS6.

Comment: I have discovered that these options appear only for proper Layers, and not for any sub-layers. To get the color coding you must reorganize your document differently.

Comment: err.. isn't that what I posted as an answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator's Layers Panel name is a bit misleading. It's really a **Layers and Object** panel - it shows layers, sublayers, and can also show all objects within a layer (if the panel options are set accordingly). The options available depend greatly upon what you have highlighted in the panel when choosing the options.

For example:

If you have an object highlighted, in this case a Path
[image]

Note the menu reads Options for "`<Path>`"...

You get this dialog showing a name, show, and lock options.

[image]

**However**, if you highlight the **Layer** rather than the **object**
[image]

Note the menu reads Options for "`Layer 1`".

You get the layer options with color and other possible settings.

[image]

It would seem you are choosing options when you have an **object** highlighted rather than a **layer**.